# Windows Store App Massive RAM usage / Memory Leak

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, ram

After running the **WACK** (*Windows App Certification Kit*) locally, I had a failure with the app **Crashes and Hangs** tests (*seemingly due to "startup" not being quick enough - there were no "crashes or hangs"*) and so refactored some of the startup code to ensure quicker start times.

*I got the app to pass the local test ok.*

But then I noticed I had somehow caused an odd **gigantic memory leak / issue** where my c# xaml win 8.1 **store app is starting**... i.e.

```
void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args);
```

with **around ~200MB shown in Task Manager**, which **quickly ramps up to ~1.5GB** before causing the app to crash.

I tried using the VS2013 Performance and Diagnostic tools to try and work out how the hell I'd managed to break my app so totally. And saw the initial ~200MB being used by around ~100

```
RuntimeTypeCache
```

objects, and then later on (the 0.7 - 1.5 GB and upwards stages of fun) a

```
List<object>
```

with various types in it.

I've tried commenting out code until the App.xaml.cs file does nothing except

this.InitializeComponent();

No joy.

I checked the Package.appxmanifest and removed everything non essential.

I **removed references** and **commented out code until** the app was essentially **an empty prism MVVM win store app - doing NOTHING... still starts at 200MB !**

What on earth is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I **solved** this, and thought the answer might *help someone else from pulling their hair out*

It **seems** that one of the **performance profiling tools** I had used to try and help with the startup time issue **had hooked into my app** and was **actually CAUSING this massive memory usage** and subsequent crashes.

I'm not sure which, but I used

1. **WACK** - unlikely
2. **Visual Studio 2013** (performance and diagnostics) - possible
3. **Application Verifier** (appverif.exe in C:\Windows\System32 - as recommended on the WACK
   documentation for ***solving*** Crashes and Hangs)

My guess is that it was 3, but this is basically an uninformed guess.

I **solved this issue by renaming the .exe** i.e. changing the

```
<AssemblyName>MyNEWAppName</AssemblyName>
```

In MyAppName.csproj

After this the app returned to normal memory usage (a tiny fraction of the 200MB - 1.7GB I had been seeing)